# How to insert dynamic input values copy one table to another table at the same time in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

Need copy one table to another table at the same time how to insert dynamic input values in MySQL using PHP?

```
$srl="INSERT INTO sales (itemname,itemquantity,price,noofproduct,total)SELECT itemname,itemquantity,price FROM hsale VALUES('".$rowcount."','".$sum."')";
```

Comment: This seems a bit broad.

Comment: How are `$rowcount` and `$sum` related to other data?

Answer (score 0):

First get data from hsale table

```
$hsale_data = $conexion->query("SELECT itemname,itemquantity,price FROM hsale");
```

Second travel the data array adding its values to a insert into query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sales (itemname,itemquantity,price) VALUES ()";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hsale_data) ){
    $query .= ",( '$row[`itemname`]',$row[`itemquantity`] ,$row[`price`] )";
}
```

Third send the query to database

```
// Print query to know if its syntaxis is alright
echo "<pre>";
echo $query;
echo "</pre>";

// Send to database
$conexion->query($query);
```